# Leaflet export GeoJSON to file

Tags: leaflet, geojson, android, download, phonegap

I'm building a mobile application with [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/) for data collection.
I'm able to place map-markers and edit their feature contents. All markers are stored in a L.layerGroup() called markerGroup;

The next step was to create button that saves and stringifies them to GeoJSON. I'm using the easy.button.plugin.

```
var exportButton = L.easyButton('fa fa-globe', function(){
  //markerDrag.toGeoJSON()
  var data = markerGroup.toGeoJSON();

  // Stringify the GeoJSON
  var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(Standorte.toGeoJSON(), null, 2));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

  // Create download but how?

}).addTo(map);
```

This works so far. If I would work on a computer, I could copy and paste the console log and create my own GeoJSON, but that's not possible in an application. So I'm looking forward for a way to download or export the collected data to a .js.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: @ghybs this doesnt help. This methods are working in regular browsers like forefox or chrome. When using this in my andoird-browser-application nothing happens

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [saveAs polyfill developed by Eli Gry](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/). It should work on Chrome for Android browser.

Check the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Leaflet GeoJSON Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="./FileSaver.min.js" /></script>

  <script>
    var freeBus = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [{
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [-105.00341892242432, 39.75383843460583],
              [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535]
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "popupContent": "This is free bus that will take you across downtown.",
          },
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535],
              [-104.99820470809937, 39.74979664004068]
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "popupContent": "This is free bus that will take you across downtown.",
          },
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [-104.99820470809937, 39.74979664004068],
              [-104.98689651489258, 39.741052354709055]
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "popupContent": "This is free bus that will take you across downtown.",
          },
          "id": 3
        }
      ]
    };
  </script>
  <script>
    function saveToFile(content, filename) {
      var file = filename + '.geojson';
      saveAs(new File([JSON.stringify(content)], file, {
        type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
      }), file);
    }

    var map = L.map('map').setView([39.74739, -105], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data © <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(map);

    var layer = L.geoJson(freeBus).addTo(map);

    saveToFile(layer.toGeoJSON(), 'test');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not working on in-app android browser