# Saving "on mouse click" created markers to be available after reloading the browser in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, point, markers

I have found that when I manually add a marker, the marker stays on the map even after reloading the browser page. Example:

```
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
```

However, all of my markers created via

```
 map.on("click", function(e){
    var m = new L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], {icon: myIcon, draggable: TextTrackCueList});
    var popup = m.bindPopup('This is a marker.   ' + m.getLatLng() ).openPopup()
    popup.addTo(map);
```

delete after every page reload.

Is it possible to save these on click markers on the map even after one reloads the page?

Answer (score 2):

As @Keagan Allan pointed out in his answer you have to somehow save info about newly created markers to be available during page reload/refresh. You can use browser session storage for that, using `Window.sessionStorage` property (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

In the simple example below, each time marker is created, it's coordinates are added to an array and this array saved in `savedMarkers` storage item.

When page is reloaded, `savedMarkers` storage item is retrieved and used for saved markers creation.

```
var savedMarkers = sessionStorage.getItem('savedMarkers');
if (savedMarkers) {
  var coords = JSON.parse(savedMarkers);
  coords.forEach(function(coord) {
    L.marker(coord).addTo(map);
  });
  }
else {
  savedMarkers = [];
}

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var coord = [evt.latlng.lat, evt.latlng.lng];
  L.marker(coord).addTo(map);
  savedMarkers.push(coord);
  sessionStorage.setItem('savedMarkers', JSON.stringify(savedMarkers));
});
```

This code is just simplest possible example. Instead of saving only coordinates, it could be any JS object with all the necessary info to recreate desired marker/feature.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of Leaflet and Javascript is limited, but you will will need to store the map clicks for the markers in a local datastore, such as a GeoJSON file and load that GeoJSON every time you refresh the page.

At the moment, the first marker stays because you hard coded the coordinates, and those coordinates are called each time the page is loaded.

The second lot of markers are generated after the map is loaded, and stored in the browser. When you refresh the page, the code clears and you lose these markers.

A quick Google search of storing Leaflet markers as GeoJSON brings up:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125036/export-leaflet-map-to-geojson

[Leaflet export GeoJSON to file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238125/leaflet-export-geojson-to-file)

You could then potentially load this GeoJSON each time the map is loaded.

https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

[Import local GeoJSON file into Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305646/import-local-geojson-file-into-leaflet)

I would start with these.